# How to retrieve a collection based on a model in backbone

Tags: backbone.js, collections, model

I want to retrieve a collection of keywords of a file with an POST request like this:

`api.host.com/file/4/keywords`

But how do I have to define my `url` and `urlRoot` Keyword model and keyword collection?
I've read the [docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-url), but I could not figured it out.

Comment: if this `api.host.com/file/4` fix? what did you try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As usual, in general but especially in JS, there are many ways to do that. I can tell you a couple of ways I would do that.

1) I would define a `keywords` Collection as

```
Keywords = Backbone.Collection.extend( { ... } )
```

Then use it as a property of the `File` Model and I would set the correct value during `initialize()`

```
File = Backbone.Model.extend({

    // the empty array [] is the initial set of models
    this.keywords = new Keywords([], { url: '/file/' + this.id + '/keywords' });

})
```

This way you can call `file.keywords.fetch()` to get the content.

2) I would define a `keywords` Collection as

```
Keywords = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    initialize: function(models, options) {
        this.modelId = options.modelId
    },

    url: function() {
        return '/file/' + this.modelId + '/keywords'
    }

});
```

And then, when needed, I would create instance like this:

```
File = Backbone.Model.extend({

    this.keywords = new Keywords([], { modelId: this.id });

})
```

To give you a complete answer, you could actually drop the `initialize()` function (if you don't need it) and write and `url` function as

```
url: function() {
    return '/file/' + this.options.modelId + '/keywords'
}
```